# How can I generate bar chart values for some time series data in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, time

I have a 'log' table which has two columns **user_id** and a **ts** (timestamp value of activity event for user):

I can use the following query to get a list of each user_id and their last activity event:

```
SELECT user_id, max(ts) as maxts
FROM "analytics"
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY maxts desc
```

What I would like to achieve:

Using the above data, I'd like to display it as a bar chart of 10 bars by grouping users according to their last active time `max(ts)`. So I'd like get the values for each "bar" (number of users) where each bar would have an equal time span.

---

My work so far:

I thought some of it might be easier to be done via a script as opposed to natively via a SQL query.

Using a script I can get the the min and max time, and split it up into 10 equal time periods. I suppose I can then write a union query where each query does a `WHERE ts < $timePeriodStart AND ts < $timePeriodEnd`.

However this does seem a bit clunky and I'm wondering if there is a more effective solution. Unfortunately using a web search I couldn't find much about generating such values, hence my question.